# Why is Primary Key's position relevant when creating a composite Foreign Key in MySql5.6?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and I've read the MySql Reference guide regarding this but no where is it mentioned that the PK should be at the end of the list while creating a composite Foreign Key.

The only requirement in the guide that talks about columns is the following -
"In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order."

If so, then why doesn't the following work?

```
alter table table_1
add constraint "fk_key_1" FOREIGN KEY "ix_key_1"  ("col_1", "col_2") REFERENCES "table_2" ("pk_col", "col_2") ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

But this works -

```
alter table table_1
add constraint "fk_key_1" FOREIGN KEY "ix_key_1"  ("col_1", "col_2") REFERENCES "table_2" ("col_2", "pk_col") ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: *"This is the only requirement according to the guide . . . "* [There seem to more that just that one.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I should've been more clearer when I said that. Edited my question to say the only requirement that talks about column order...

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key has to match the primary key (or some key, but preferably the primary one) -- both the types and order.

If this works:

```
FOREIGN KEY "ix_key_1"  ("col_1", "col_2") REFERENCES "table_2 ("col_2", "id_col") ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

It is because the primary key on `table_2` is defined as `(col_2, id_col)` rather than `(id_col, col_2)`.

Comment: Do you mean the an index in table_2 has been defined as (col_2, id_col)? If so, when does this index get created automatically? Because I did not explicitly create one, and the primary key in table_2 is only id_col. (These are test tables that I created to try an understand this concept)

Comment: @user6927714 . . . MySQl extends SQL to allow foreign key references to any index columns.  So you must have an index on `(col_2, id_col)`.  This could also be created via the `unique` keywork.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not have an index created explicitly with columns (col_2, id_col), but I read that MySql creates indexes automatically if they don't already exist, so perhaps it implicitly creates an index with the order above.

Comment: @user6927714 . . . The index is created automatically on the *referencing* table (`table_1`) with a foreign key declaration.  The index is not created on the *referenced* table.